# SWReveal - change frontviewcontroller on application start

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using `SWRevealViewController` to implement a side menue in my application. in storyboard i have set the `sw_front` segue. this segue is loading the MainView on every start of application. now i want to give the user the possibility to change the first displayed viewcontroller.

How can i do that? I know there is a property `setFrontViewController:` but where should i use this to load the front during application start?

I cant use it in the `viewDidLoad` of the `frontViewController` which i set in Storyboard. That could not be a solution, so i would need to do it in every view controller to grab and check the "should load another view controller as first or `frontViewController`"

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if you found the my solution correct.

Comment: @jogshardik your solution will work, too. I have found a simple solution which is also update stable. your answer is also correct, i will mark it. but please also check my solution, i will add it as answer for other people.

Comment: okay when i'll get time, i'll implement and check your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have understood what you have problem and what you want to do i have also the same kind of thing to do, so what i have done create the custom segue in the swrevealviewcontroller that i have also mention in my code.
and modified the two methods perform and loadstoryboardcontroller methods, you can also see in my code.
It will definetely work for you as well.

Have a happy coding cheers.

My code is below:

I have done this the code you need to change is below.

```
- (void)loadStoryboardControllers
{
if ( self.storyboard && _rearViewController == nil )
{
//Try each segue separately so it doesn't break prematurely if either Rear or Right views are not used.
@try
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:SWSegueRearIdentifier sender:nil];
}
@catch(NSException *exception) {}

@try
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:SWSegueFrontIdentifier sender:nil];
}
@catch(NSException *exception) {}

@try
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:SWSegueRightIdentifier sender:nil];
}
@catch(NSException *exception) {}
@try
{
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:SWSegueCustomIdentifier sender:nil];
}
@catch(NSException *exception) {}
}
}
#pragma mark - SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController segue identifiers

NSString * const SWSegueRearIdentifier = @"sw_rear";
NSString * const SWSegueFrontIdentifier = @"sw_front";
NSString * const SWSegueRightIdentifier = @"sw_right";
NSString * const SWSegueCustomIdentifier = @"sw_custom";

#pragma mark - SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController class

@implementation SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController

- (void)perform
{
SWRevealControllerOperation operation = SWRevealControllerOperationNone;

NSString *identifier = self.identifier;
SWRevealViewController *rvc = self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *dvc = self.destinationViewController;

if ( [identifier isEqualToString:SWSegueFrontIdentifier] )
operation = SWRevealControllerOperationReplaceFrontController;

else if ( [identifier isEqualToString:SWSegueRearIdentifier] )
         operation = SWRevealControllerOperationReplaceRearController;

else if ( [identifier isEqualToString:SWSegueRightIdentifier] )
operation = SWRevealControllerOperationReplaceRightController;

else if ( [identifier isEqualToString:SWSegueCustomIdentifier])//your conditional segue
operation = SWRevealControllerOperationReplaceFrontController;

if ( operation != SWRevealControllerOperationNone )
[rvc _performTransitionOperation:operation withViewController:dvc animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: How do you switch between @"sw_front" and your custom one.

Comment: You have to put your condition there in the as i mention the there in the code

Comment: Sorry, I have a question. How to use SWSegueCustomIdentifier and sw_custom?  Have any example as reference?
https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/820

Answer (score 0):

@jogshardik has the correct answer for my question but i found also another solution.

In your storyboard you are connecting a custom segue "sw_front" with your viewcontroller. This viewcontroller is on every initial start your first front viewcontroller. So you just have to check in this controller if you need to set another front viewcontroller.

i set up a notification in this "sw_front" viewcontroller and also in your Side Menue View Controller add the notification handler.

if you want to change the view just fire the notification and let do the notifaction handler the rest (set your `setFrontViewController:` property).

So this also works and is update stable if you need to keep attention on newer versions.

if this information is not enough for you, give me a hint and i will post an example code or project when i have time.

Comment: Which method of "sw_front" viewcontroller sends such notifications? It can't be initWithCoder. Right?